# csv file to dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to write from a csv file to a dictionary.

But:

1. The first word from a row should be the key
2. All other words in the row should be seperate values for this key.

My code so far:

```
def coordinates(text):
    import csv
    reader = csv.reader(open(text))
    d = {}

    for row in reader:
        key = row[0]
        d[key] = row[1:]
    print(d)

coordinates('luchthavens2.csv')
```

With this code all items from the row are the key in my dictionary.

Who can help?

EDIT:

Input file looks like this:

```
BIN,"Bamiyan","Bamiyan","Afghanistan","AF",34.800000,67.816667,701,"Afghanistan",\N,\N,1149361
BST,"Bost","Bost","Afghanistan","AF",31.550000,64.366667,701,"Afghanistan",\N,1134720,1149361
CCN,"Chakcharan","Chakcharan","Afghanistan","AF",34.533333,65.266667,701,"Afghanistan",\N,\N,1149361
```

All from an excel file called luchthavens2.csv, the positions of the text are A1-A2-A3-etc.

You should find it here: https://expirebox.com/download/bb8cb3a39f9be041743a8b86db89093b.html

Output:

```
{
'CCN,"Chakcharan","Chakcharan","Afghanistan","AF",34.533333,65.266667,701,"Afghanistan",\\N,\\N,1149361': [],
'BST,"Bost","Bost","Afghanistan","AF",31.550000,64.366667,701,"Afghanistan",\\N,1134720,1149361': [],
'BIN,"Bamiyan","Bamiyan","Afghanistan","AF",34.800000,67.816667,701,"Afghanistan",\\N,\\N,1149361': []
}
```

EDIT:

I've changed my input file to a text file, then back again to a csv file. Strangely enough this worked, I can read it without any problems.

Comment: Do you have any sample data you can show us? Like what does `text` look like usually?

Comment: Something like this (only one row): BIN,"Bamiyan","Bamiyan","Afghanistan","AF",34.800000,67.816667,701,"Afghanistan",\N,\N,1149361

Comment: @Roelland if row is: BIN,"Bamiyan","Bamiyan","Afghanistan","AF",34.800000,67.8166‌​67,701,"Afghanistan"‌​,\N,\N,114936, what's output?

Comment: What does 'separate values for this key'? It's not really clear what the exact structure you're trying to build is, maybe you should provide an example (edit your question, rather than in comments)

Comment: Please explain what output should look like.

Comment: The code you've shown us works perfectly. The error, therefore, must be in what you *haven't* shown us. Please [edit] your question to include the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. Please include sample input, the actual and expected output, and any error code that occurs. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: I dont think there is anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Strange, for me it really doesn't work. I'm using eclips...

Comment: Can you show what is the output you are currently getting

Comment: {'BST,"Bost","Bost","Afghanistan","AF",31.550000,64.366667,701,"Afghanistan",\\N,1134720,1149361': [], 'CCN,"Chakcharan","Chakcharan","Afghanistan","AF",34.533333,65.266667,701,"Afghanistan",\\N,\\N,1149361': [], 'BIN,"Bamiyan","Bamiyan","Afghanistan","AF",34.800000,67.816667,701,"Afghanistan",\\N,\\N,1149361': []}

Comment: We believe that it doesn't work for you. But you need to show us with precision what doesn't work. Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** program. Please copy-paste the resulting entire short program into your question. Please copy-paste the actual input, the actual output, and type in the expected output.

Comment: can you link your sample input file. I am pretty sure something is wrong there

Comment: Can I add the excel file? I don't find this, thanks for the help already!

Comment: Upload it to somefile hosting like expirebox and then post the link here

Comment: Thanks for uploading the file. When you open that file in Excel, is "BIN" in A1, and is Bamiyan in A2? How did you generate that file? It is not exactly in the form you've described. (Rant: we would have seen this already if you had **copy-pasted** the data into your question.)

Comment: Man your data is not proper, there are imbalanced quotes. fix it and you should be good/

Comment: It is data I got from my lecturer, can't really order it as it's an excel file of ~10 000 rows. Altough I just uploaded just one with the first 3 rows.

Comment: Why are are using 2 times double quotes for your strings`""Bamiyan""` ?

Comment: Is it an excel file or a csv file?

Comment: The example file does not match at all the example in the post. It is a very irregular csv file...

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following,

```
import pprint
import csv


def coordinates(text):
    ret = {}
    with open(text, 'r') as fp:
        reader = csv.reader(fp)
        for row in reader:
            key = row.pop(0)
            ret[key] = row
    return ret


data = coordinates('data.csv')
pprint.pprint(data)
```

On the following file,

```
$ cat data.csv 
AAA,"Blub",25.25
BBB,"Blob",27.27
```

Then you will get,

```
$ python stackoverflow.py 
{'AAA': ['Blub', '25.25'], 'BBB': ['Blob', '27.27']}
```

Comment: I still have the same problem actually! But maybe it has to do with the input file (see replies on the post). Thanks for the effort anyways!

Answer (score 1):

In your input file, the quotation marks are messed up.

```
"BIN,""Bamiyan"",""Bamiyan"",""Afghanistan"",""AF"",34.800000,67.816667,701,""Afghanistan"",\N,\N,1149361"
"BST,""Bost"",""Bost"",""Afghanistan"",""AF"",31.550000,64.366667,701,""Afghanistan"",\N,1134720,1149361"
"CCN,""Chakcharan"",""Chakcharan"",""Afghanistan"",""AF"",34.533333,65.266667,701,""Afghanistan"",\N,\N,1149361"
```

should be

```
"BIN","Bamiyan","Bamiyan","Afghanistan","AF",34.800000,67.816667,701,"Afghanistan",\N,\N,1149361
"BST","Bost","Bost","Afghanistan","AF",31.550000,64.366667,701,"Afghanistan",\N,1134720,1149361
"CCN","Chakcharan","Chakcharan","Afghanistan","AF",34.533333,65.266667,701,"Afghanistan",\N,\N,1149361
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you desired output.
Your data is not in proper CSV format

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('luchthavens2.csv'))
d = {}

for row in reader:
    row = row[0].split(',')
    key = row[0]
    d[key] = row[1:]
```

Rather you dont need a CSV module for this thing because your data is not proper CSV

Below code will solve your problem without CSV module

```
d = dict()
with open('luchthavens2.csv') as fh:
    for row in fh:
        row = row.split(',')
        key = row[0]
        d[key] = row[1:]
```